# How to commit files including deleted file using svn ant

Tags: svn, ant, tortoisesvn

I checkout files from the SVN repository, replaced content for few files and deleted few files. Now I want to commit all the changes including the deleted file. I am using below code but the deleted files still remains in the repository. Please guide.

```
<svn svnkit="true" javahl="false" username="${svn.user}" password="${svn.pass}">
                <add>
                    <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*.txt" />
                    </fileset>
                </add>
                <commit message="Committing changes..">
                    <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*.txt" />
                    </fileset>
                </commit>
            </svn>
```

Comment: Have you tried including a `<delete>` block for these files?

Comment: Yes i did, but dint work out.